# pdf outline extraction by dumppdf.py in pdfminer

Tags: python, pdfminer

```
ShimpeinoMacBook-Pro:samples shimpei$ dumppdf.py -T JJJ.pdf
<outlines>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/dumppdf.py", line 272, in <module>
    if __name__ == '__main__': sys.exit(main(sys.argv))
  File "/usr/local/bin/dumppdf.py", line 269, in main
    dumpall=dumpall, mode=mode, extractdir=extractdir)
  File "/usr/local/bin/dumppdf.py", line 151, in dumpoutline
    outfp.write('<outline level="%r" title="%s">\n' % (level, q(s)))
NameError: name 's' is not defined
```

now I try to extract TOC(outline)information from pdf with pdfminer,but it doesn't go well beause of error above.
how can I solve this problem?

Comment: Please produce a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Ok, I modified the text a bit

Comment: Try using the latest version of `pdfminer-six`.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. A user at this site helped me.

He changed the line 151 on `dumppdf.py` to:

```
outfp.write('<outline level="%r" title="%s">\n' % (level, q(title)))
```